# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest wants authentication but NSURLConnection not

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection

I´m trying to get some `JSON` from a server. When I want to accomplish that with the convenience method `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]` the request fails with **error code -1012**, which means "*userCancelledAuthentication*". That would be ok, but there is no authentication challenge from that URL! Making a connection with `[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: delegate:]` works just fine, without any authentication challenge (I´m getting an response, but not the delegate call `-(void)connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`)

This is really strange to me since I´m using the same request for both calls.
I tried allocating the queue directly inside the call, and then tried to make a global queue retained by the object sending the request. Both did not make the asynchronous request with completion handler work. The response from the `[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: delegate:]` call is exactly what I expect.

Can anybody explain why there is this difference between `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]` and `[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: delegate:]`?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: delegate:` during the download the connection maintains a strong reference to the delegate. It releases that strong reference when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled, as Apple docs states.

On the other hand, if you use `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` if authentication is required in order to download the request, the required credentials must be specified as part of the URL. If authentication fails, or credentials are missing, the connection will attempt to continue without credentials, also according to Apple docs.

So, you have not response on the delegate call `-(void)connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` because no authentication is really needed, and that's why `NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: delegate:` works best on this case.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Though, also a block, like which is passed as completionHandler, maintains strong references to the objects referenced by the code in it. Since I do not need authentication, `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` should be possible, too, shouldn´t it? But the request done this way fails.

Comment: Yes, by the docs it should be possible too. And what is happening is strange.

Comment: As a workaround I made my own self-retained object to mirror this functionality. Still, I am really curious to find out the reason behind the failure

Comment: Indeed, this thing started to bug me too... but maybe it was just designed like that.

Comment: Thanks :D Since I did not find any other thread about this method, I thought I´m just crazy, or the solution is too simple. If you want I can give you the code, that I used to mirror the functionality. It doesn´t even need an operationQueue

Comment: Yes, sure. I'd like to take a look on the code that mimic yours. How would you like to share it?

Answer (score 0):

I built some workaround now, a class that mimics the NSURLConnection´s `sendAsynchronousRequest` method. The file is below. It should be easy to migrate existing code, since the block´s parameters are the same, only the operationQueue is not needed

The object allocated by the class method is retained by itself until the request finishes.

the .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SNSPApiRequest : NSObject
+(void)startRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *))requestFinished;
@end
```

the .m

```
#import "SNSPApiRequest.h"

@interface SNSPApiRequest ()
@property NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) void (^requestFinished)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error);
@property (strong, nonatomic) void (^deconstructSelf)();
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLResponse *response;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *data;
@end

@implementation SNSPApiRequest

+(void)startRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *))requestFinished {
    SNSPApiRequest *apirequest = [[SNSPApiRequest alloc] init];
    apirequest.data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    apirequest.requestFinished = requestFinished;
    apirequest.deconstructSelf = ^{apirequest.connection = nil;apirequest.response = nil;apirequest.data = nil;};
    apirequest.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:apirequest];
}

#pragma mark - NSUrlConnectionDataDelegate

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.data appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.response = response;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    self.requestFinished(self.response, self.data, nil);
    self.deconstructSelf();
    self.deconstructSelf = nil;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    self.requestFinished(self.response, nil, error);
    self.deconstructSelf();
    self.deconstructSelf = nil;
}
```